# What would be a better way to write this Sass Animation delay function?

Tags: sass, css-animations

So I discovered that I can do math and assign variables in Sass. So I went to creating a delay routine stack so I can eaisliy retime and push forwards the other css3 animations in a queue of sorts without having to keep scrolling up and down the page looking for that stupid line.

I know this is not a real function, but for the most part it works! and once setup saves a bit of time. But setting it up is the most annoying, and then if I change my mind of the order.

Bah, otherwise I wanted to share this snippit of code for those that searched for the same thing.

```
$Atime: 2.0s;
$Btime: $Atime + 0.2s;
$Ctime: $Btime + 1.0s;
$Dtime: $Ctime + 0.3s;
$Etime: $Dtime + 0.3s;
$Ftime: $Etime + 0.3s;
$Gtime: $Ftime + 1.0s;
$Htime: $Gtime + 1.2s;
$Itime: $Htime + 0.3s;
$Jtime: $Itime + 0.4s;
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess not since it's too simple when relooking at it. Closed.